# Minimal Fortran for Sublime 3

Tags: fortran, sublimetext3

How to install Minimal Fortran for Sublime text 3 in linux?
I also tried this code for sublime in windows and worked well but it didn't work for that in linux.

```
import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = '7183a2d3e96f11eeadd761d777e62404' + 'e330c659d4bb41d3bdf022e94cab3cd0'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://sublime.wbond.net/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
```

And also `install package` in Command Pallete --> Minimal Fortran. err: Unable to download Minimal Fortran, Please view the console for more details.

Comment: What means "it does not work?"?

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Package Control: Error downloading package. unable to resolve host address ‘codeload.github.com’ downloading https://codeload.github.com/315234/MinimalFortran/zip/master.
error: Package Control

Comment: I downloaded the package manually. how to install it?

Comment: Ok got it, I just copied the files in package folder.